# Can't build DKMS kernel module

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, kernel, modules

I'm on Raspian Stretch and an RPi2. I'm trying to install `xtables-addons-dkms`. This was the output of `apt-get` on my first attempt:

```
Setting up xtables-addons-dkms (2.12-0.1) ...
Loading new xtables-addons-2.12 DKMS files...
It is likely that 4.14.79-v7+ belongs to a chroot's host
Building for 3.6-trunk-rpi, 4.14.79+ and 4.14.79-v7+
Building initial module for 3.6-trunk-rpi
Error!  Build of xt_ACCOUNT.ko failed for: 3.6-trunk-rpi (armv7l)
Consult the make.log in the build directory
/var/lib/dkms/xtables-addons/2.12/build/ for more information.
Setting up gcc-4.6 (4.6.4-5+rpi1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Setting up linux-kbuild-3.6 (3.6-1~experimental.1+rpi2+b2) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.6-trunk-rpi (3.6.9-1~experimental.1+rpi7) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 3.6-trunk-rpi
Error!  Build of xt_ACCOUNT.ko failed for: 3.6-trunk-rpi (armv7l)
Consult the make.log in the build directory
/var/lib/dkms/xtables-addons/2.12/build/ for more information.
```

`linux-headers-3.6-trunk-rpi` was pulled in automatically by `apt-get`. I'm not sure why as my kernel version is `4.14.79-v7+` going by `uname -r`. I've tried removing those headers and installing the `raspberrypi-kernel-headers` package. That at least seemed to install the correct headers for my kernel into `/usr/src`. However I still get similar errors:

```
Unpacking raspberrypi-kernel-headers (1.20181112-1) ...
Setting up raspberrypi-kernel-headers (1.20181112-1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 4.14.79+
Error!  Build of xt_ACCOUNT.ko failed for: 4.14.79+ (armv7l)
Consult the make.log in the build directory
/var/lib/dkms/xtables-addons/2.12/build/ for more information.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 4.14.79-v7+
Error!  Build of xt_ACCOUNT.ko failed for: 4.14.79-v7+ (armv7l)
Consult the make.log in the build directory
/var/lib/dkms/xtables-addons/2.12/build/ for more information.
```

As the errors advise I consulted the make log and there's just a range of errors in there, the first one being:

```
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.14.79-v7+'
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf 

    || (                \
    echo >&2;                                                       \
    echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";           \
    echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
    echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";      \
```

**Edit:** I have tried running the `make oldconfig && make prepare` command advised above (and as suggested by @MatsK). However it fails with this output:

```
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/kconfig/conf
scripts/kconfig/conf  --oldconfig Kconfig
#
# configuration written to .config
#
scripts/kconfig/conf  --silentoldconfig Kconfig
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/arm/tools/syscall.tbl', needed by 'arch/arm/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd-common.h'.  Stop.
arch/arm/Makefile:319: recipe for target 'archheaders' failed
make: *** [archheaders] Error 2
```

There were also a couple of compiler errors in the make log e.g.

```
/var/lib/dkms/xtables-addons/2.12/build/extensions/xt_LOGMARK.c:90:11: error: implicit-function-declaration]
  else if (nf_ct_is_untracked(ct))
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

And some other similar ones about implicit function declarations, not sure how important these are.

Any ideas as to what I might need to do to fix this?

Comment: Have you done what is recommended `Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.` in the make log ?

Comment: @MatsK I just tried it, I get this: `HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/kconfig/conf
scripts/kconfig/conf  --oldconfig Kconfig
#
# configuration written to .config
#
scripts/kconfig/conf  --silentoldconfig Kconfig
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/arm/tools/syscall.tbl', needed by 'arch/arm/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd-common.h'.  Stop.
arch/arm/Makefile:319: recipe for target 'archheaders' failed
make: *** [archheaders] Error 2`

Comment: Please add it to the question, the output is unreadable in the comment field.